# VST Plugin That Maps Piano Roll To Scale

Tags: midi, daw, vst

I am new to EDM, so forgive my ignorance. I'm currently using Tracktion 7 DAW.

When inside the piano roll, I would like it if the notes could be mapped to a particular scale.
Is there a VST that performs this functionality?
I have tried MelodicFlow however I don't seem to be able to get it to do what I wanted.
Please note that I just want to enter notes, not chords.

Thanks.

Comment: The function of a VST plugin is primarily to process audio samples in real time, or offline. The functionality you are asking for is somewhat outside the scope of what a VST was intended for and is more a core function of the DAW you have chosen to use. Might be that you need to look at something that is a little bit more customizable, such as reaper?

Comment: Cubase can do a lot along those lines, using logical edit or transform -  transpose or force to key, scale, etc. I don't know of any plugin that can do it. As Mark says, "VSTs" tend to be audio devices, not midi.

Comment: I have unfortunately come to that conclusion also. As a hack, I currently create an empty track and fill it with the notes of the scale I desire and set it as a ghost track. I was hoping something like RapidComposer might help, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I don't know exactly how other DAWs handle this, but in FL Studio you have the possibility to create a ghost channel (which you also currently use in your DAW) and in the piano roll go to Settings > Helpers > Scale Highlighting which let's you hightlight every kind of scale for every key possible. [Here](https://i.redd.it/qacniw63v1h11.jpg) you can find a picture which shows the possibilities in a bit more details.

Comment: The plentiful and simple features of the piano roll in FL Studio have won me over. Initially I was hoping for functionality similar to that of the program Bosca Ceoil. Specifically being able to 'automagically' alter a track's scale, e.g. from a Minor to say Hungarian.